# Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, wordpress, e-commerce

As titled, I'm getting this error on my site. I have checked through the IE8 developer debugging tool, and I have got the following code that caused the error.

```
<!-- slider js code start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    if(eval(document.getElementById('coda-slider-1')))
    {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
        //jQuery.noConflict(); var $j = jQuery;
    }
});
```

I have included the screenshoot from Chrome debugging tool.

http://img857.imageshack.us/i/javaerror.jpg

http://img204.imageshack.us/i/javaerror2.jpg

Please help me to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: is the empty `$()` a typo? Also, why the eval call?

Comment: what is this line: `if(eval(document.getElementById('coda-slider-1')))` supposed to do?

Comment: Is... Is this code `eval`ing a DOM element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    if($('#coda-slider-1').size())
    {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
        //jQuery.noConflict(); var $j = jQuery;
    }
});
```

Your original code says "select nothing with jQuery, and apply this ready handler to it."  The correct long-hand syntax would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...
```

Also note that I have removed `eval` because it should never, ever be used, unless it can't possibly be avoided.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your error screenshots, it appears that jQuery is not defined (at least not with the `$` alias.  Have you included the script on your page? If so, are you calling `jQuery.noConflict()` before your ready handler is bound?

Try putting this script tag above both the code you posted, and the script tag for the coda slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

As pointed out by kingjiv in the comments below, I was mistaken, and `$().ready` will work (though it is not recommended).  I believe my first update, noting that jQuery appears not to be defined, is the actual issue here.

Comment: I don't mean to complain, but I've now been downvoted twice with no explanation. I don't mind if you think I'm wrong, but I'd appreciate knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Ender, do you mind to help me to fix this issue? I really have no idea on what to do, as I'm not familiar with coding. Would you mind to leave your email so that I could contact you? I do appreciate a lot if you could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jone - Sorry, but I'm not going to post my email address in a public space like this.  Try following the suggestions I've made.

Comment: Ender, I have followed your twitter, please follow me too, so that I can send messages to you. Thanks.

Comment: Again, sorry but no. What is wrong with using this comment thread?

Comment: I have no idea on those coding stuff, I would like to hire someone to help me, if you can offer me some time to help, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I have sent an email to you (m**d*****l*@gmail.com) , Please have a check. Thank you.

Comment: My guess is the downvotes are because `$().ready(handler)` is valid, just not recommended.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to check for the existence of `coda-slider-1`?

No need to use eval, and if you're using jquery, may as well select the element with jquery:

```
if($("#coda-slider-1").length>0){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- `$().ready` isn't recommended. Use
  `$(document).ready(function` or
  simple `$(function`.
- Why using `document.getElementById`
  if jQuery already lookup elements
  using selectors in a crossbrowser
  way? Just do `$("#some").length` to
  see if it exists.
- Also in your case I think is good to
  ensure that the `codaSlider()` method
  is loaded before calling.

Correted code:

```
$(function() {
    if ($("#coda-slider-1").length > 0 && $("#coda-slider-1").codaSlider) {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
    }
});
```